# Format default Date pattern in MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern

I have a date field in my Mongo Model and I want to format it a little better for better readability.

The field in my Model looks like this - `createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }` and this gives me the timestamp in a format like this - *2020-03-17T20:14:21.851Z*

How can I format this in the Model itself when the operation on the model takes place?

Answer (score 0):

This is how data of datetime type is stored in Mongodb. It is not possible to store it in a different format as a datetime type. You can keep a string in the format you want, but this will cause problems with queries. So it doesn't make sense.

The truth is to format the datetime data in frontend (React).